# Need Help to Set cookie to remember button click and disable it for X minutes

Tags: php, jquery, cookies

im trying to make cookie remember the button clicks for about X minutes after the last click, even if reload the page, and then enable it again after X minutes of clicks, but i cant do it, is there anyone to help me do that? 
This is the Set limit code, im done with it i just need to set the cookie someone for me.

```
(function(){
    var click_counter = 0;
    jQuery('.button').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var el = jQuery(this);
        click_counter += 1;
        if (!el.hasClass('inactive')){
            // should be activated
        };
        if (click_counter >= 6){
            // deactivate
            el.addClass('inactive');
             alert('Message');
        };
    });
})();
```

Thank You

Comment: You are trying. Okay. But i dont get your question. Why is there a question mark at the end of the sentence anyway?

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand, I would do something like this:
Try this:

```
function writeCookie (key, value, mins) {
    var date = new Date();

    // Get unix milliseconds at current time plus number of hours
    date.setTime(+ date + (mins * 3600000)); //60 * 60 * 1000

    window.document.cookie = key + "=" + value + "; expires=" + date.toGMTString() + "; path=/";

    return value;
};
```

Usage:

```
<script>
writeCookie ("myCookie", "clicked", 2);
</script>
//for 2 mins
```

And we want to check when page load:

```
<script>
$c_value = document.cookie;
if ($c_value == "clicked") {
// whatever you code to deactivate is

}
</script>
```